# Como colocar borda em um item selecionado na ListView?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Como colocar uma borda em um item da ListView quando o usuário selecionar aquele item na aplicação android?

Comment: O seu `ListView` é multi seleção?

Comment: @Androiderson na verdade é Simples seleção

Comment: Se é simples seleção, não faz sentido destacar o item selecionado. Use o `selector` padrão e dispare qualquer evento necessário logo que o item é selecionado.

Comment: @Androiderson sim, mas o usuario ira selecionar e depois sim, devera passar pra a proxima pagina, é mais questao de UX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siga estes passos:

1 - Adicione o atributo `android:choiceMode` à *ListView*,

para permitir seleccionar apenas uma linha:

```
android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
```

para permitir seleccionar mais de uma linha:

```
android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
```

Para *customizar* a aparência da selecção necessita de um Selector.

2 - Crie, na pasta *res/drawable*, os *drawable* a serem usados no Selector:

**list_item_selected.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

        <solid android:color="cor do fundo quando selecionado"/>
        <stroke 
            android:color="cor da borda quando selecionado"
            android:width="3dip"/>
</shape>
```

**list_item_unselected.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

        <solid android:color="cor do fundo quando não selecionado"/>
        <stroke 
            android:color="cor da borda quando não selecionado"
            android:width="3dip"/>
</shape>
```

Coloque as cores ao seu gosto!
Se em algum caso quiser que a cor seja a do fundo da ListView use `@android:color/transparent`

3 - Crie o Selector:

**list_item_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_selected" android:state_pressed="true"/>
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_selected" android:state_selected="true"/>
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_selected" android:state_activated="true"/>

    <!-- não seleccionada -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_unselected"/>
</selector>
```

4 - Atribua o Selector ao *background* do **item** da lista:

```
android:background="@drawable/list_item_selector"
```

<sub>**Nota:** Não testei, espero não me ter enganado em nada.</sub>